# Intel MKL for Python by Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, intel-mkl

I installed Intel MKL library in Anaconda for Python 3. I need to use the optimization library of Intel MKL particularly the [trust region method](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/nonlinear-optimization-problem-solvers/nonlinear-least-squares-problem-with-linear-bound-constraints.html#nonlinear-least-squares-problem-with-linear-bound-constraints).
I have the documentation of Intel MKL for [trust region](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/nonlinear-optimization-problem-solvers/nonlinear-least-squares-problem-with-linear-bound-constraints.html#nonlinear-least-squares-problem-with-linear-bound-constraints), however, the documentation looks like belonging to C/C++. Is there any documentation on Intel MKL for Python? How can I call Intel MKL in my Python script?

Comment: here's the document:https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl.html

Comment: Thanks! But I cannot find where the optimization documentation is. Particularly the trust region method. The link looks like about installing it for numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only the below Packages have been upgraded officially to use MKL directly from python

1. NumPy
2. NumExpr
3. SciPy
4. Scikit-Learn
5. mkl-service

You could use this packages to make use of mkl from python for the other mkl  solvers and algorithms like trust region in your case you should write the solver in c/c++ and call the c program from python.

Please find below link to call a c function in python.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-a-c-function-in-python/

below is some sample psudo code for reference.

```
import ctypes
mkl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libmkl_rt.so")
print(mkl.mkl_get_max_threads())
```